# Dropdown value changed by click only one time why?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Object Type <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Cloth</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Toy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Furniture</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Household</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instrument</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){

    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){

      $(".dropdown:first-child").text($(this).text());
      $(".dropdown:first-child").val($(this).text());

   });

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I select the value from the drop down menu drop down title is changed by the menu(e.g.,Cloth,Toy,Furniture,etc). But, after that the drop down menu is vanished. Why?

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/cCrul/1nwtyje9/ or maybe I didn't understand.

Comment: I would suggest fixing your markup first. 2 `</div>` tags at the bottom with no open div tags and a dangling `li` wrapping a `ul` structure but not inside a `ul`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because this line `$(".dropdown:first-child").text($(this).text());` means that you want to change the content of the whole `.dropdown` menu to the text of the clicked element, change the selector to select the right element which is the `.dropdown-toggle` like :

```js
$(function() {

  $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown-toggle").text($(this).text());
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Object Type <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Cloth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Toy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Furniture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Household</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Instrument</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: If I would show the caret with the value, it is better.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `<li>` outside of a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) is invalid. `li` is a list element, it's not supposed to exist outside of a list.

Then, `$(".dropdown:first-child")` selects the first element with the `.dropdown` class (and NOT the first element INSIDE it). Which is, your lonely `<li>` element. And you replace *everything* in that element with some text, so it vanishes. Select `$(".dropdown-toggle")` instead.

Finally, you can optimize your code and accelerate it by :

- caching $(".dropdown-toggle") instead of accessing it in the DOM and building a jQuery object every time you click
- use `e.currentTarget.innerText` instead of building another jQuery object at every click with `$(this).text()`

Which reduces your code to an efficient one-liner.

```js
const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle")

$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(e => $dropdownToggle.text(e.currentTarget.innerText))
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Object Type <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Cloth</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Toy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Furniture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gift</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Household</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Instrument</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```